# Why doesn't rowSums work on data frame created using pivot_wider in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to work out total volume remaining and the average volume for a large data set, which I thought would be a simple case of using rowSums and rowMeans on the data frame I created using pivot wider but I keep encountering the same errors.

```
df<-data.frame("parent"=c("001","001","001","001","002","002","002","002",
                     "003","003","003","003","004","004","004","004"),"tube"=c("tube1",
                      "tube2","tube3","tube4","tube1","tube2","tube3","tube4",
                      "tube1","tube2","tube3","tube4","tube1","tube2","tube3","tube4"),
                     "microlitres"=c(100,120,60,100,NA,200,100,120,
                    60,100,120,40,100,120,400,NA))

pivot_wider(df,names_from = tube,values_from = microlitres)->df

df$sum<-rowSums(df,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get "**Error: x must be numeric**", and then when I alter the code to

```
df$sum<-rowSums(as.numeric(df),na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get "**Error: List object cannot be coerced to double**".

I've spent a long time googling and haven't come across anything that helps. I'm sure there's a simple fix but I just can't see it. I've tried using mutate with nested rowSums, I've tried unlist(), and converting it to a matrix. I'd be very grateful for any help and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the output is the one you had in mind:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum_cols = sum(c_across(tube1:tube4), na.rm = TRUE),
         mean_cols = mean(c_across(tube1:tube4), na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  parent tube1 tube2 tube3 tube4 sum_cols mean_cols
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 001      100   120    60   100      380       95 
2 002       NA   200   100   120      420      140 
3 003       60   100   120    40      320       80 
4 004      100   120   400    NA      620      207.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`df$sum <- rowSums(sapply( df, as.numeric), na.rm=TRUE)`

The problem is that `pivot_wider` treats some of the columns as character by default and `as.numeric()` takes a vector as inputs.

```
> df
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  parent tube1 tube2 tube3 tube4   sum
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 001      100   120    60   100   762
2 002       NA   200   100   120   422
3 003       60   100   120    40   646
4 004      100   120   400    NA   624
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for my original data, but it's very helpful to know how the functions behave as I think I sometimes struggle with that aspect so thank you!